# Tying teffilin knot everyday

Tags: tefilin, tosfot, tying-knots-kosheir, chulin-tractate

What is the "tying" referred to in [תוס‘ ד"ה ואידך הני שכיחן in Chullin 9a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=chulin&daf=9a&go=Go), in which Rebbeinu Tam seems to hold that tying teffilin every day is not obligatory?

(It is not referring to putting on teffilin, because that is obligatory. I think it may be referring to making the daled-knot every day.)

What I really want to know is what Rabbeinu Eliyahu's ruling, requiring tying every day, actually requires.

Comment: Do you really think he means every day and not just every time you put them on?

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you really think sam does?

Comment: @msh210 Based on how he phrased it that's what it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading the Tosfos properly, it appears that it is a matter of actually tying and untying the knot every day rather than just settling it around ones head (as we do). The point of the Tosfos seems to be that one does not undo the knot and redo it the next day and one of the proofs is that it is forbidden to tie the knot of the tefillin, not just because of muktzah, but because it is a permanent knot which is asur.

The point of the Tosfos seems to be that the fact that it is listed in the second list means that it is not something that is done every day (in which case it would not even be in the second list) but is common enough to not be in the first list.